# No Year in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, xetex, biber

[image]

[image]

Errors are given at the images.

This is file.tex minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,openany]{book}

% xelatex file.tex
% bibtex8 file or biber file

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Latin]{serbian}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,russian,english,german}

\usepackage[style=numeric-verb,autopunct=false,babel=none,defernumbers=true,language=english,backend=biber,texencoding=utf8,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{file.bib}

\begin{document}

This is first \cite{k:10}, second \cite{k:11}, third \cite{s:15}, fourth \cite{z:09}, fifth \cite{o:02} and sixth \cite{o:03} citation. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is file.bib:

```
%% Biblio %%

@manual{k:10,
    editor    = {Morgan J. Hurley},
    title     = {SFPE Handbook of Fire Protection Engineering},
 organization = {Society of Fire Protection Engineers},
    publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
    ISBN      = {978-1-4939-2564-3},
    edition   = {V},
    year      = {2016}
}

@Report{s:15,
title       = {Склады  нефти  и  нефтепродуктов - Противопожарные  нормы},
institution     = {Строительные Нормы и Правила},
number      = {СНиП 2.11.03-93},
year        = {1993}
}

@Report{z:09,
title       = {Pravilnik o izgradnji postrojenja za zapaljive tečnosti i o uskladištavanju i pretakanju zapaljivih tečnosti},
institution     = {Službeni list SFRJ},
year        = {{20/1971 i 23/1971}}
}

@report{o:02,
title       = {The 100 Largest Losses 1974 - 2015: Large property damage losses in the hydrocarbon industry},
institution     = {Marsh \& McLennan},
date        = {{2016}}
}

@report{o:03,
title       = {Report on Indian Oil Terminal Fire at Jaipur on 29. October, 2009.},
institution     = {Independent Inquiry Committee, Committee Constituted by MoPNG Goverment of India},
year        = {{29. January, 2010.}}
}

@incollection{k:11,
    author    = {D. M. Johnson},
    title     = {Vapour Cloud Explosion at the IOC Terminal in Jaipur},
    booktitle = {Hazards XXIII - Symposium Series 158},
    publisher = {IChemE},
    ISBN      = {978-0-8529-5557-4},
    year      = {2013},
}
```

Comment: There is probably a solution, but finding it would be much easier if the example you posted would be a bit more minimal. For example is it really necessary to use special fonts so we can not compile it ourselves if we don't have them? http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/36296

Comment: After your suggestion, I make  revision on my post! @samcarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the result you desire?

- The year is inserted if the bibliography is called inside an English language environment
- besides that, I added the `csquotes` packages as advised in a warning
- to get the year in the handbook, I changed it to `book` type
- the option `babel=none` is deprecated

---

```
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
    %% Biblio %%

    @book{k:10,
        editor    = {Morgan J. Hurley},
        title     = {SFPE Handbook of Fire Protection Engineering},
        organization = {Society of Fire Protection Engineers},
        publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
        ISBN      = {978-1-4939-2564-3},
        edition   = {V},
        year      = {{2016}}
    }

    @Report{s:15,
        title       = {Склады  нефти  и  нефтепродуктов - Противопожарные  нормы},
        institution     = {Строительные Нормы и Правила},
        number      = {СНиП 2.11.03-93},
        year        = {1993}
    }

    @Report{z:09,
        title       = {Pravilnik o izgradnji postrojenja za zapaljive tečnosti i o uskladištavanju i pretakanju zapaljivih tečnosti},
        institution     = {Službeni list SFRJ},
        year        = {{20/1971 i 23/1971}}
    }

    @report{o:02,
        title       = {The 100 Largest Losses 1974 - 2015: Large property damage losses in the hydrocarbon industry},
        institution = {Marsh \& McLennan},
        year        = {{2016}}
    }

    @report{o:03,
        title       = {Report on Indian Oil Terminal Fire at Jaipur on 29. October, 2009.},
        institution     = {Independent Inquiry Committee, Committee Constituted by MoPNG Goverment of India},
        year        = {{29. January, 2010.}}
    }

    @incollection{k:11,
        author    = {D. M. Johnson},
        title     = {Vapour Cloud Explosion at the IOC Terminal in Jaipur},
        booktitle = {Hazards XXIII - Symposium Series 158},
        publisher = {IChemE},
        ISBN      = {978-0-8529-5557-4},
        year      = {2013}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt,oneside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Latin]{serbian}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,russian,english,german}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric-verb,autopunct=false,autolang=none,defernumbers=true,language=english,backend=biber,texencoding=utf8,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{file.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*} 

\begin{english}
\printbibliography[title=Literatura]
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, now it's everything OK. Problem was in the  English language environment. Thank you! @samcarter